Understanding "Both differential and integral calculus make use of the notion of convergence of infinite series to a well-defined limit".
I was reading the book "Algorithms for Optimization" and in the Introduction part of the book it is written that:

Modern calculus stems from the developments of Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz (1646–1716) and Sir Isaac Newton (1642–1727). Both differential and integral calculus make use of the notion of convergence of infinite series to a well-defined limit.

I'm wondering what does the last sentence mean? I'm familiar with the Rieman integral for calculating the definite integrals but how the indefinite integrals and differentiations are related to the "notion of convergence of infinite series"?

Presumably it's in reference to Taylor series.

Perhaps the idea is that a function on an interval can be approximated by dividing the interval into smaller and smaller sections. Summing over contributions works, because there is convergence. This is true if the function is sufficiently well-behaved on the interval.

I can see this if we replace "series" with "sequences" but if we insist on series then @PrincessEev has the most likely suggestion.
